# Linear maps between manifolds

Tags: geometry, differential

J. M. Lee p. 55 Introduction to Smooth Manifolds -- "it makes no sense to talk about a linear map between manifolds."

Why?

Comment: Well, actually we can speak about linear maps in context of smooth manifolds: given a smooth function $f:M\to N$ its differentiate is a linear map at each point $T_xM\to T_{f(x)}N$.

Comment: A linear map $T$ should satisfy $T(ax + by) = aT(x) + bT(y)$ (for all $x,y,a,b$).  But what does it mean to take a linear combination of points on a manifold?

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no algebraic structure (addition, scalar multiplication) on a smooth manifold with no extra structure. (E.g. what is addition on a 2-sphere? What is scalar multiplication?)

A linear map is a map that plays nicely with those structures.

Comment: Excellent -- thanks